# problemas con el tamaño de mi aplicación

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación que sería una suerte de Paint donde se pueden dibujar figuras y pegar imágenes, el problema es que al ir poniendo figuras y desplazándolas el tamaño de la aplicación aumenta mucho (al iniciar es de unos 90MB) y luego crece (mas de 600MB) y se incrementa también al mover las figuras aunque la cantidad de figuras no varíe.

Lo que mas me llama la atención es que al borrar y hacer null a todas las figuras el tamaño de la aplicación no se reduce.

¿Que es lo que puede estar pasando? o que puedo hacer para mejorar el código.

Agrego un código que creé para ver que pasaba:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Prueba extends JPanel{
int x=0;
int y=0;
boolean Graficar = false;
  public Prueba(){  
   Timer tiempo = new Timer();//creamos una instancia para el Timer 
   TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    public void run(){  
     x=x+1;
     if(x>1000){
     x=0;
     y=y+10;
    }   
  if(x>100){
    Graficar = true;
  }
  if(y>20){
    Graficar = false;
  }
repaint();
  }};
// se inicia la animacion   
tiempo.schedule(task,0, 50);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {// metodo para dibujar componentes en Panel 
try{
 super.paintComponent(g);
  if(Graficar){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    BufferedImage Imagen = ImageIO.read(new File("/Imagenes/images.jpg")); 
    g2.drawImage(Imagen, x +150, y+150, null);  
    BufferedImage Imagen2 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Imagenes/descarga.png")); 
    g2.drawImage(Imagen2, x, y+300, null);  
    BufferedImage Imagen3 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Imagenes/images.png")); 
    g2.drawImage(Imagen3, x, y+500, null);
    g2.setColor(Color.GREEN); // color de la figura 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        int x2 = (int)(Math.random()*1000);
        int y2 = (int)(Math.random()*1000);
        g2.fillRect(x2, y2, 100, 100);
        g2.fillOval(x2+150, y2, 100, 100);
    }
   g2.setColor(Color.CYAN); // color de la figura   
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       int x2 = (int)(Math.random()*1000);
       int y2 = (int)(Math.random()*1000);
       g2.fillRect(x2, y2, 100, 100);
       g2.fillOval(x2+150, y2, 100, 100);
   }
  g2.setColor(Color.RED); // color de la figura 
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      int x2 = (int)(Math.random()*1000);
      int y2 = (int)(Math.random()*1000);
      g2.fillRect(x2, y2, 100, 100);
      g2.fillOval(x2+150, y2, 100, 100);
  }
 g2.dispose();  
}   
g.dispose();
}catch(Exception ex){}
}//end paintComponent

public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame jf = new JFrame();
  jf.add(new Prueba());
  jf.setVisible(true);
  jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}

}
```

Y pasa lo siguiente, arranca con unos 27MB y va creciendo hasta 90MB pero cuando deja de graficar no baja nada el peso de la aplicación!!! y eso que acá no creo ninguna variable en donde almacenar nada.

Lo mismo me pasa con mi aplicación nada mas que los valores son mucho mas grandes.

Comment: No te alarmes, el problema es que Java mantiene esa memoria "ocupada" para no tener que reclamarla en el futuro. Si quieres que tu aplicación tenga un límite máximo debes usar la opción `-Xmx<tamaño>` (estoy usando el JDK 8.0, lo especifico porque esa opción no es estándar), en ese caso la aplicación "crecerá" hasta la opción máxima que le des.

Answer (score 1):

No veo problemas en el código que copiaste. De todas formas los valores de memoria que mencionas son usuales si estas trabajando con varios componentes visuales.
Por otro lado, un tema que debes tener en cuenta, es que cuando dejas de usar un objeto no necesariamente vas a ver al instante descender la memoria RAM utilizada por el programa. 
Esto ocurre porque el manejo de memoria en Java se hace a través de un mecanismo denominado Garbage Collector (recolector de basura). Simplificando la explicación, este recolector mantiene una lista de los objetos en memoria y sus referencias. Cuando un objeto perdió todas sus referencias y se volvió entonces inaccesible desde el programa, se marca para ser eliminado de la memoria RAM. Ahora bien, desde que fue marcado hasta que es realmente eliminado puede pasar un tiempo o no...eso lo manejará el Garbage Collector según corresponda. 
Si usas el parámetro de Virtual Machine "Xmx" para darle un techo de memoria pedida al operativo, la memoria utilizada irá creciendo hasta llegar cerca de ese techo y luego el recolector activará la eliminación de los objetos marcados, lo que provocará una caída abrupta de memoria RAM utilizada para empezar todo el ciclo de nuevo.